# Setting up python web handler in windows IIS in restricted environment

Tags: python, web, iis

I have Anaconda Python distribution on my office laptop. I made a web application with intention to use it within the team. I have access to a Windows server that has IIS. We already have a similar C# web app on this server. We are already using this application locally within the team for a long time. But this is the first time we are trying a python web application.

Limitations

1. We have one python setup on the server. But not able to install standard python on the server. It just stop mid installation.
2. We do not have the installation packages for Anaconda. It was installed by a different infrastructure team member since we do not have permissions to install.
3. We cant download any installation files on our laptops.
4. The server does not have internet access. But we have admin access.

Is there a way I could use venv to create a local folder with all the required modules (requests, flask, jinja2 etc...) and copy that folder on the server and use it to host the web page on the server? Is this possible?

I created venv and copied the libraries one by one from the site-packages folder. I am unable to use pip to install any packages. I am using all the available packages in the standard Anaconda distribution, which is quite good. I copied this venv to the server and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Whatever it is Anaconda Python or standard python, you need to install at least one of it to make server has configuration related to python. Simply copy-pasting the folder didn't do anything. So contact your anaconda team to provide the installation package or install the standard python.

Comment: That's impossible. IIS does not natively support Python, so you need something bridging the requests (HttpPlatformHandler for example), https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info Then you need to publish your Python app as a self-contained executable.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.